# Why would you create a table with primary key but without and index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

When I heard of this first time, I really don't understand why people want to do this. Anybody know why and how? Does any other database engine allow for it?Forgive my ignorance.

I am using SQL Server. Online book said SQL server will enforce a clustered index to primary key when we create it by default. If we don't like it or other reason, we can also specify non-clustered index to the primary key. Based on my knowledge, SQL server will apply different algorithm according to different index. My next doubt is why and when we need non-clustered index on primary key?

Comment: Is your question "Why have a primary key field with no index?" or "Why have a primary key field with a non-clustered index?"

Comment: Both of them. Thanks to point them out

Answer (score 3):

why not? PK is constraint - logical entity while index is a physical entity which is used only to speed up queries and is not required by data model/logic

so we can (theoretically) use any constraint without having indexes - by price of performance.

sometime it is useful. in very, VERY rare and specific cases.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on Use cases.

- **Indexes cost** - space and time for building - this can hit insert/update speed. You may not be able to afford this in your use case.
- **Not Used much** - your table may have other columns used as keys for joins, lookups etc and so the primary key could just be an artificial key for consistency.
- **Other columns need indexes** - hybrid of the above two for example - you may choose to only index other columns. There is only one cluster in the table (the physical ordering of the data) and another index my need it. I've changed PKs from clustered to non clustered for this reason on occasion.

Though I must agree with you in that I suspect that it's rarer these days.

Comment: In third case, you mean another column is better for clustered index than primary key column?

Comment: how about primary key? It is left without any index or need non-clustered index?If without any index, I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @FebWind -  in some cases its better to cluster on another column. A clustered index is really just another way for saying the order of the rows in the table. It's like a natural index as opposed to a calculated one. A PK is a unique constraint not an index.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no explicit reason to limit a PK to a clustered index.

There is not a different "algorithm" for a non-clustered index.
A clustered index is merely table ordered so it is not a separate physical index.

If you have a non key causing a lot of row splits you may not want to use a clustered PK.

Consider memory-optimized tables of SQL 2014.  The PK is non-clustered hash.

Comment: The idea of the non clustered hash makes sense doesn't it when considering in memory DBs.

Comment: @PreetSangha Did I imply a non-clustered hash did not make sense for memory-optimized table?  Clearly it was presented as an example that made sense.

Comment: It sounds PK at lease needs a index ,either clustered or non-clustered index.Am I right? If so, it makes more sense.

Comment: @Blam - no I completely concur with the suggestion.

Comment: Your questions are covered in the documentation.  A table can have zero or many indexes.  A table can only have one clustered index.